# FATAL : the database system is starting up error postgresql error in a docker container

Tags: postgresql, docker, gradle

I have been trying to dockerize a spring boot application which needs to be connected to a postgresql db. When I build an run the container though it crashes throwing up the error mentioned in the title. Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong? Thanks

My Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys B97B0AFCAA1A47F044F244A07FCC7D46ACCC4CF8

RUN echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ precise-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list


RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python-software-properties software-properties-common postgresql-9.5 postgresql-client-9.5 postgresql-contrib-9.5 openjdk-8-jdk
ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64

USER postgres

RUN    /etc/init.d/postgresql start &&\
    psql --command "CREATE USER vova WITH SUPERUSER PASSWORD 'vova';" &&\
    createdb -O vova springbootdb

RUN echo "host all all  0.0.0.0/0 trust" >> /etc/postgresql/9.5/main/pg_hba.conf

RUN echo "listen_addresses='*'" >> /etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf

USER root

# create the work directory
RUN mkdir -p  /usr/src/smartExtensionsBackend
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/pgsql/data

WORKDIR /usr/src/smartExtensionsBackend

# copy all source files to the work directory

COPY . /usr/src/smartExtensionsBackend

#grab gradle

RUN apt-get install -y gradle

#build application

RUN gradle build

#start application

CMD ["sh","init.sh"]

#expose port 8083

EXPOSE 8083
```

I extracted out the postgres log file from inside the container

```
2017-10-19 03:12:51.333 UTC [21] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2017-10-19 03:11:46 UTC
2017-10-19 03:12:51.374 UTC [21] LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
2017-10-19 03:12:51.376 UTC [20] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2017-10-19 03:12:51.377 UTC [25] LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
2017-10-19 03:12:51.607 UTC [27] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
2017-10-19 03:35:26.946 UTC [35] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2017-10-19 03:13:03 UTC
2017-10-19 03:35:27.220 UTC [36] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
2017-10-19 03:35:27.735 UTC [39] postgres@postgres FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2017-10-19 03:35:28.250 UTC [42] postgres@postgres FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2017-10-19 03:35:28.765 UTC [45] postgres@postgres FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2017-10-19 03:35:29.280 UTC [48] postgres@postgres FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2017-10-19 03:35:29.797 UTC [51] postgres@postgres FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2017-10-19 03:35:30.314 UTC [54] postgres@postgres FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2017-10-19 03:35:30.829 UTC [57] postgres@postgres FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2017-10-19 03:35:31.345 UTC [60] postgres@postgres FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2017-10-19 03:35:31.862 UTC [63] postgres@postgres FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2017-10-19 03:35:32.379 UTC [66] postgres@postgres FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2017-10-19 03:35:32.896 UTC [69] postgres@postgres FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2017-10-19 03:35:32.969 UTC [70] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
```

Comment: try editing your `/etc/init.d/postgresql` - add `-w` key to `pg_ctl start` so it would wait it to start before running other statements

Comment: Woops my bad I forgot the the init.sh. The `/etc/init.d/postgresql` in the RUN command works fine. It is the same command in init.sh that is casusing the problem. Here is my init.sh file, `/etc/init.d/postgresql stop
/etc/init.d/postgresql start
gradle bootRun`

Comment: Why don't you use a postgres docker image?